# Matrix conversion to txt file

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, genfromtxt

I've been studying Machine Learning lately and now I'm working on Factorization Machines (Rendle's first papyer, 2010).

I've found later on https://github.com/srendle/libfm so I can apply that for specific train / test data.

The matrix (i.e training data) has to be in .txt format. What I've done so far working on a csv data file on Python in order to build the feature vectors X (intoduced here http://www.algo.uni-konstanz.de/members/rendle/pdf/Rendle2010FM.pdf) which gives me the matrix ... in Python.

Is it possible to extract it in .txt format or anything like that?

Comment: Define ".txt format". txt files contain no headers or special blocks or compressed sections or anything -- it's all just ordinary bytes. You could rename your `data.csv` file to `data.txt` and it would technically be a valid .txt file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

```
import numpy
m = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
f = open('f.txt', 'w')
numpy.savetxt(f, m, fmt='%s')
f.close()
```

**edit**
f.txt:

```
1 2
3 4
```